QFT Books for refreshing skills PhD
I would like to brush up my QFT skills, as I would like to do my doctorate in this field (Higgs, possibly with SUSY). Family planning got in the way, so this project has been delayed somewhat.
It's just not easy for me to decide which book with corresponding exercises I should tackle to get fit.
Of course, it should be reasonably up-to-date, including solutions.
With Peskin Schröder, for example, you get the feeling that the exercises are more like small research assignments than meaningful tasks...
I am also familiar with all the current recommendations, but I would like to get your opinion so that the time invested is not completely wasted.
I still have some books on my bookshelf from my student days:
Srednicki
Sidney Coleman QFt lectures
Peskin and Schröder
Steven Weinberg 1 to 3
Schwartz Matthew
Klauber: 1 and 2 student friendly QFT
Mark Thomson
Anton Zee: QFT Nutshell
Björken Drell: QFT
Rebhan
Kugo gauge theory
Griffiths Introduction to particle physics
Which book and exercises would you recommend?
Kind regards
Matthias

Matthias, with this background, it should be your prospective thesis advisor to tell what to read/do.

Yes, that's right, but I don't have a supervisor yet. For professional reasons, I can't start until October 25. I am currently planning my first interviews. I'm just looking for learning materials and exercises that I can use to familiarize myself with the subject in advance.

You might look at "Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell

It really depends on your current skill level and expectation.
If you have studied some qft before in some detail, Zee's Nut is a great read.
If you have only a vague or no recollections of what qft is, I would recommend Peskin & Schroeder.
If you want a more formal and detailed (and also much more demanding) approach to qft go for Weinberg.
These are personal choices, so other people may well have other preferences.
PS. Note also that in my profile you have a link to my website that has a very detailed set of notes on qft.

Thank you very much. I own both, peskin and weinberg. I will give peskin a chance because there are solutions available from the exercises.
